# Using python dictionaries to create flashcards from a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of 50 terms I need to learn and instead of copying and pasting each one into a flashcard app I am trying to put each term and its definition into a Python dictionary.

I have the following code:

```
terms = """1   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words 2 Term - definition..."""

definitions = {}


for word in text.split():
    if word.isdigit():
        definitions[word+1] = ???
```

I want the code to read through the strings and if it hits a digit it should save the next word it runs into e.g. "Alliteration" as the key and all of the words after it, up until the next number, as the value e.g.

> "the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words"

Any idea on how to write the code that solves the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
import re

str1 = """1   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of 
    nearby words 2 Term - definition..."""
str2 = re.split("\d+",str1)
dict1 = {a.split("-")[0].strip():a.split("-")[1].strip() for a in str2 if '-' in a}
```

Comment: @Justin O'Brien try dict1 = {a.split("-")[0].strip():a.split("-")[1].strip() for a in str2 if '-' in a}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace all the digits to some specific value and split the string on that value.

```
In [24]: terms = """1   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words 2 Term - definition..."""

In [25]: new_term = re.sub("\d+", "?-", terms)

In [26]: new_term
Out[26]: '?-   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words ?- Term - definition...'

In [27]: li =new_term.split('?-')
In [28]: li
Out[28]:
['',
 '   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words ',
 ' Term - definition...']
In [29]: list(map(lambda t: t.strip(), li[1:]))
Out[29]:
['Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words',
 'Term - definition...'
```

You can use anything instead of `?-` that you won't have anywhere else in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the terms in a nested list, like so,

```
terms = [ [word, definition], [word, definition], etc ]
```

Then loop over `terms`

```
definitions = {}


for item in terms:
  word = item[0]
  meaning = item[1]
  definitions[word] = meaning
```

EDIT:
I guess if you could put the terms in an array you could just as easily manually put them in a dictionary, so I'm guessing the list of terms is the way it is and isn't changing, in which case my answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split with any number. And then, in the resulting list, split to get the word and its meaning. Store it to your dictionary!

```
>>> terms
'1   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words 2 Term - definition...'
>>> d={}
>>> import re
>>> dict(l.strip().split('-') for l in re.split('[0-9]',terms) if l)
{'Alliteration': ' the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words', 'Term ': ' definition...'}
>>> d
{'   Alliteration': ' the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words ', ' Term ': ' definition...'}
```

That is,

```
>>> re.split('[0-9]',terms)
['', '   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words ', ' Term - definition...']
>>> [l for l in re.split('[0-9]',terms)]
['', '   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words ', ' Term - definition...']
>>> [l for l in re.split('[0-9]',terms) if l]
['   Alliteration- the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words ', ' Term - definition...']
>>> [l.strip().split('-') for l in re.split('[0-9]',terms) if l]
[['Alliteration', ' the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words'], ['Term ', ' definition...']]
>>> dict(l.strip().split('-') for l in re.split('[0-9]',terms) if l)
{'Alliteration': ' the repetition of a speech sound in a sequence of nearby words', 'Term ': ' definition...'}
```

Without using list comprehension,

```
>>> for l in re.split('[0-9]',terms):
...     if l:
...             key,value = l.strip().split('-')
...             d[key]=value
...
```

Here, instead of `d[key]=value` you can use `d[key]=d.get(key,'')+value+'\n'` if a word in terms can have more than one meaning!

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you explain where the `l` in `l.strip()` comes from?

Comment: `l` is the iteration variable for the for loop used in list comprehension.